# how to mysql group by zerofill?

Tags: mysql, group-by, zerofill

```
SELECT count(w.c1) AS count
     , w.c1 AS color
FROM
  data w
GROUP BY
  w.c1
ORDER BY
  w.id DESC
LIMIT
  50000;
```

I'm wondering, is there any kind of mysql query to group by zerofill values, i have all values in c1 as rgb code '`0002500034`' `(r=000/g=250/b=034)`, after query it shows like `000250034->250034`

Comment: Why not save them in HEX or better in binary with an int ?

Comment: Did you define your `c1` column as `zerofill`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the LPAD MySQL function ? LPAD(str, len, padstr)

```
SELECT count(w.c1) AS count
 , LPAD(w.c1, 9, '0')  AS color
FROM
  data w
GROUP BY
  w.c1
ORDER BY
  w.id DESC
LIMIT
  50000;
```

You can also turn your column type into CHAR(9).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(w.c1) AS count
     , concat(w.c1) AS color
FROM
  data w
GROUP BY
  w.c1
  order by w.c1 desc
LIMIT
  50000;
```

just tried and it works fine,
 also i'll try your version

edit:
my query:

```
+-----------------+-----------+
| Variable_name   | Value     |
+-----------------+-----------+
| Last_query_cost | 16.599000 |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

vs your's

```
+-----------------+----------+
| Variable_name   | Value    |
+-----------------+----------+
| Last_query_cost | 3.599000 |
+-----------------+----------+
```